What is going on with this hook?

I made it last night, saved my blend file and when I loaded it back today it looked like this..? I believe it may have something to do with normals and I tried recalculating them but it seems like the issue persists. When I turn off smooth shading it looks even worse:

Any help is appreciated!

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Try to go into the Data panel > Geometry Data > Clear Custom Split Normals Data, if it doesn't work please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/
